# image does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to display multiple images from the row called image in products table from the database to the view, but am getting this error `Property [image] does not exist on this collection instance.` from the `@foreach(json_decode($products->image, true) as $product)` loop , I have tried other solutions but they don't work.

Here are the codes

Controller

```
  public function store(Request $request) 
  { 

    $Input=$request->all();
    $image=array();
    if($files=$request->file('image')){
        foreach($files as $file){
            $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move('images',$name);
            $image[]=$name;

        }

    } 
   product::create(array_merge($Input,
   [
    'image' => json_encode($image),

    ])); 
    return redirect()->back(); 

    }
```

Blade view

```
     @foreach(json_decode($products->image, true) as $product)
      <img src="{{url('images',$product->image)}}" alt="">
     @endforeach
```

Product model

```
   protected $table='products';
  protected $primaryKey='id';
  protected $fillable=['name','price','image','stock'];

public function images()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\product', 'image');
}
```

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Just so we dont have to guess, please tell us which line the error is generated on. ALWAYS show ALL the error message, please dont summarise it

Comment: The error is generated from the ` @foreach(json_decode($products->image, true) as $product)` @RiggsFolly

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to store this image info in another table linked with the `id` of Product, rather than obfiscate it in a json string?

Comment: just confirm you mentioned `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in `<form>` tag.

Comment: Yeah I mentioned `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form @SahilGupta

Comment: I had the table called images and it was related with products but I couldn't know how to display images  in database so I asked and somebody answered with that json_decode @RiggsFolly

Comment: Since you do have an images table that's separate, can you show the model for `product`? Though you apparently never store the image into the images table, so it may be empty...

Comment: I have updated question with product model @aynber

Comment: I'm going to guess that `$products` is a collection of products, so images would not be in that collection anyway. What you need to do is iterate through $products, and each product should have one image. So `@foreach($products as $product) @if(!empty($product->images) <do image src stuff> @endif @endforeach`

Comment: I'm getting `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '('"` while there is no `':'` in the loop this error comes from if statement@aynber

Comment: Also in database each product has multiple image so i want to display all images of a product @aynber

Comment: Hah, missed a closing parenthesis. That's what I get for doing it without an editor. Replace each - with a new line: `@foreach($products as $product) -
        @if(!empty($product->images) ) -
         <do img stuff here>
        @endif -
    @endforeach -`

Comment: Also, your product model does not have a proper definition, and will probably fail. I'll add an answer with what it should like, for better formatting

Comment: If you need any code, tell me I'll provide @aynber

Answer (score 0):

Your product model should look like this, to have multiple images:

```
protected $table='products';
protected $primaryKey='id';
protected $fillable=['name','price','image','stock'];

public function images() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\images');
}
```

You may need to add the keys as well, in case they don't match up right, such as :

```
return $this->hasMany('App\images', 'product_id', 'id');
```

Once this is done, you can iterate through the images like this:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
   @foreach($product->images as $image)
       <img src="{{url('images',$image->filepath)}}" alt="">
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: That relationship doesn't store images in (images table) and also am getting the error `"Undefined property: stdClass::$images` @aynber

Comment: Can you `var_dump($products)` and show what that contains?

Comment: Even if I do `var_dump` it keeps showing the error @aynber

Comment: The var_dump was to see what the structure was, not to fix the error.